# Using CSS to display items as ordered list

Tags: html, css

I'm very confused about how to display things as lists is css. I see that there is an option to display an element as a list-item, but how can I specify that the parent is supposed to be an ordered list?

For example:

```
<style>
  .list_item{
    display:list-item;
  }
  .ordered_lit{
    display:???;
  }
</style>
<div class="ordered_list">
  <div class="list_item"></div>
  <div class="list_item"></div>
</div>
```

Thanks!

Comment: What's your actual problem, and why aren't you just using an ordered list?

Comment: You can't style a parent on the basis of a child in CSS. I think you can with Javascript but that might be more effort than its worth. Try adding a special class to each LI and that has a sub ordered list.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't need to specify the parent's `display` property, just specify the `list-style-type` (which will take care of displaying the counter, which I suspect is the problem you're trying to solve) in the CSS for the 'list-item' elements:

```
div.counter {
    display: list-item;
    list-style-type: decimal;
}
```

The above CSS works with the HTML:

```
<div>
    <div class="counter"></div>
    <!-- identical elements removed for brevity -->
    <div class="counter"></div>
</div>
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/cjHtx/) (confirmed working in Chromium 28/Ubuntu 12.10, [*not* working in Firefox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18937698/using-css-to-display-items-as-ordered-list/18937734?noredirect=1#comment27963684_18937734), apparently).

If you only need to support those browsers that are able to work with pseudo-elements, then you have the option of using CSS-generated counters:

```
div.parent {
    counter-reset: pseudoListNumbering;
}

div.counter::before {
    counter-increment: pseudoListNumbering;
    content: counter(pseudoListNumbering, decimal-leading-zero);
}
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/cjHtx/1/).

References:

- [`display`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/display).
- [`list-style-type`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/list-style-type).
- [Using CSS Counters](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Counters?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=CSS%2FCounters).

Comment: The jsfiddle rendering has “0.” as the item number for all the items in Firefox.

Comment: In the first jsfiddle, it is essential that there is a left margin set, too. Without left margin or padding, there is no room for the numbers, so they won’t appear.

Comment: note ([jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Sv7sY/)) that the "opposte" operation works in both Firefox and Chrome, i.e. styling an li with "display: block" will hide the number and not increment the native counter...this is what I was looking for, so might help someone else too!

Comment: The first approach confirmed still not working in Firefox 51

Answer (score 0):

> *how can I specify that the parent is supposed to be an ordered list?*

Simple answer: **You can't**. There is no special `display` value to specify a parent for `list-item` elements.

And by the way: you really should use proper HTML tags for the case: `ul`/`ol` instead of `div`s. ***Why?*** Because otherwise you'll have to remember about things like `margin`/`padding` by yourself. With `ul`/`ol` browsers do this out of the box. Check [**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/vJg5t/) for sample problem you can face.

Comment: What is the motivation behind other display types, e.g. replacing table/tr/td with display equivalents? I agree in principle that predefined tags for your exact purpose should be preferred. Was it just that tables in particular needed this treatment? I appreciate the argument that pseudo-li would need a different prefix for each instance within a pseudo-ol, however, each li within an ol *does* get a different prefix by some mechanism, right?

Comment: Making your HTML closer reflect the intent by using the right tags makes things like screen reader experience much better.

Comment: That's what I would have thought, yeah, but the hate for tables is real, and the movement toward display-based formatting seems pretty popular, so I don't really know what to think. I'm happy to use predefined elements, especially when it comes to tables.

Comment: @JohnP it's because they're wrong. There are instances where the numbering in a list *is not semantic* but actually *just styling*, and thus you should absolutely not use the html elements for it. [Example](https://codepen.io/Hashbrown/full/BaZzvWV). Implementing something like this using real `ul`s would be **horrible** for screenreaders. Like with tables, if you're only wanting the layout, use css, if your data is *actually* tabular, then use the elements. There is no "always use X never use Y"

Answer (score -1):

There is no value for `display` to generate an ordered list. See the spec: http://dev.w3.org/csswg/css-display-3/#display

Because the unordered list requires no count, every element is prepended with the same content.

Answer (score -1):

Css display value 'list-item' is only a behaviour like a li-element: insert a bullet before content and insert a break after element. There is no css display value for a numerical or alphabetical listing.